# Time In Relation to Motion

Tags: relativity

So if I understand right, the Theory of Relativity says that time moves differently for someone going near the speed of light than it does for someone standing "still". Since we are moving through space, would this speed just be calculated from the point of origin, or do you have to account for current movement and direction?

Answer (score 0):

> So if I understand right, the Theory of Relativity says that time moves differently for someone going near the speed of light than it does for someone standing "still".

Kind of, but not really. This statement assumes something that is not allowed in relativity: an absolute reference frame. There is no meaning to "moving at the speed of light" or "still". All you can talk about is relative motion. So a more precise statement would be

> So if I understand right, the Theory of Relativity says that I will observe time "moving differently" for someone going near the speed of light relative to me than it does for someone standing "still" relative to me.

and the answer there is "yes".

---

> Since we are moving through space, would this speed just be calculated from the point of origin, or do you have to account for current movement and direction?

The above discussion might shed some light (pun always intended) on this issue here. We are moving through space relative to other things in space, sure. But thinking about what you observe relative to some other reference frame needlessly complicates things. You can just talk about the speed of things relative to you. No need to pick some other point in the universe.

Comment: So relativity aside, this still leaves the fact that the higher your velocity the slower time passes, correct?

Comment: @JamesReimer Relative to another observer, yes. The point I was trying to make is that "your velocity" isn't actually a well defined thing. If you jump on a spaceship and fly away from the Earth near the speed of light, on your spaceship you will still see time to be the same. The fact that you are moving fast relative to Earth does not suddenly make you age less, for example. There is no preferred reference frame. You can only talk about relative velocities.